# Java- Man on a Bridge

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with a program where a person starts in the middle of a 7 foot bridge. Here's the description:

> > Someone is standing at the center of a bridge that is 7 ft bridge long. Their stride is exactly one foot. They can’t control the direction they are going but the bridge is very narrow and they can only go forward or backward with each step.
> >
> > Write a program that calculates how many steps the person will walk before exiting the bridge. Have the program execute this simulation 1000 times and as your output display the average and greatest number of steps taken. (Hint: generate a random number that is either 0 or 1 and let one equal forward and the other backward). Do this 20 times so that you can make comparative observations.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class prog214a
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random generator = new Random();
        System.out.println("1000 iterations");
        int runs = 0;
        int iter = 1000;
        double count = 7.0 / 2.0;
        int random;
        System.out.println("Run\tAvarage\tGreatest Number of Steps");
        // for(runs=1;runs<20; runs+=1)
        // {
        for (iter = 1000; iter > 1; iter -= 1)
        {
            double tries = 1;
            double avg = count / tries;
            random = generator.nextInt(2);
            if (random == 0)
            {
                count -= 1;
            }
            if (random == 1)
            {
                count += 1;
            }
            if (count <= 0 || count >= 7)
            {
                System.out.println("#" + runs + ":\t" + avg + "\t" + count);
                count = 0;
                runs += 1;
            }
            tries += 1;
        }
        // }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this an assignment for a programming class?

Comment: I'm having trouble here. I see an assignment and some code, but no well constructed question. Where exactly are you stuck? What confuses you? We're not going to  your homework for you of course, and I assume that you're not asking us to. But please know that asking a good question takes some effort, just as answering does too. Please put a little more effort into your question here so we will be able to help you.

Comment: My bad on that,
what I mean is, My program is spewing out 1.0 and -1.0 for all the answers, and it is giving me 200 rows instead of 20. What is wrong in the code, that is making it give me these strange answers?

Comment: Atleast you should reset `count` to 3.5 and not 0 in the last `if` block. Also in the `for` condition make it `iter > 0` because now your only doing 999 loops. And what do you mean with 200 rows? Because your doing 999 iterations.

Comment: The Program is supposed to run 1000 iterations, but print 20 results.
I fixed both of those issues you pointed out and it still gives me one of 2 answers, (avg and Greatest number of steps)0.5 and -0.5 or 6.5 and 7.5. Also, it gives me 69 outputs, instead of 20.

Comment: You never use 20 in your code except in a comment, so how is the program supposed to know that is should only do 20?

Comment: You're using the `count` variable for the position and the total number of steps. You should have separate variables for them.

Comment: i took it out using the comment, because someone suggested it on a diffrent forum...

Edit: I added the for loop, and it gives me 70 outputs now instead of 20..

Answer (score 3):

Part of your problem is the way you're approaching it. Your code should show a neat path from the abstract set of things you're doing to an actual mechanical execution.

Your first problem is establishing an algorithm, or sequence of events you want to happen:

```
Print out position
Decide direction
Move
Repeat n times
```

Now lets translate those gross steps into code. We do this by making methods for each:

```
public void printPosition();
public int findDirectionVector();
public void updatePosition(int move);//move is a vector
public void runSimulation(int iterations);
```

Lets now fill out the control method:

```
public void runSimulation(int iterations) {
   for (n = 0; n < iterations ; n++) {
       executeIteration();//simple! 
   }
}

private void executeIteration() {
  printPosition();
  updatePosition(findDirectionVector());
}
```

As you can see, we're making sure **each method does exactly one thing**. We are also leaving certain things (such as Position) as a member variable of the class rather than trying to handle it as a variable you're passing around. However, this is a change, so lets look at your initialization and class structure:

```
public Simulation {
  private int position = 0;
  private int iterations = 0;//number of times the person moves before you stop!

  public Simulation(int iterations) {
    this.iterations = iterations;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Simulation sim = new Simulation(1000);//Run with 1000 iterations
    sim.runSimulation();
  }

  //your other methods go here
}
```

Now, when you want to run this 1000 times you just have to wrap `sim.runSimulation()` in a for loop.

I've left out one very important check (has the man exited the bridge?) and the implementations of the other methods for you to do.

Comment: The problem with this, is that I just started programming a few months ago, and I have no idea what is going on in your explanation. In this assignment we are supposed to use loops, decision making, random numbers, input, and output.How would I program something like this? I think the part that is confusing me is making it run 1000 times, and making it output 20 outputs:/

Comment: One data set is a thousand iterations.  So you run a random number of steps forward and backwards one thousand times and capture the average and greatest number of steps over those 1000 iterations.  You do this 20 times giving you 20 average number of steps and 20 greatest number of steps.

Comment: omg, you just opened my eyes 0.0
i was trying to solve for how many steps it would take the whole time, but now I see that Im supposed to focus on the steps and avg.
one thing though, how would you capture the greatest number of steps?

Comment: one iteration: take xRandomSteps; do 1000 times.  collect in an array, the highest xRandomSteps will be max for that data set; do 20 times.

Comment: now its not working again:/
whenever I reset count, it keeps it as 3.5 no matter what..

Comment: do you still have double count = 7.0 / 2.0; in your code?  Post an update.

Comment: No I took that out and changed it into 7.0/2;

Comment: @malymieczek Apologies for not being able to respond sooner; mostly what I was attempting you to do was to break the problem into parts, while showing how to translate that into a program. Ping if you want more guidance.